# Tor Browser unable to connect to any website (Endless Loop)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I've been trying to connect to the Tor network, but my Tor Browser is stuck in endless loop.

At first I tried to connect through a VPN (Cyberghost VPN then to Tor network). It did not work.
After that I tried to connect only to Tor network with no other VPN Connections active.
At last I tried to connect to Tor network with a deactivated Firewall.
I also checked my Hardware Firewall and my Router Logs.

I have also tried to use different bridges.
Last I reset my IP through command line and restarted my machine.

LOG #1 (With Cyberghost VPN active) :

```
8/6/2015 3:01:56 AM.181 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
8/6/2015 3:01:56 AM.181 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
8/6/2015 3:01:56 AM.181 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
8/6/2015 3:02:02 AM.950 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
8/6/2015 3:02:02 AM.951 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
8/6/2015 3:02:03 AM.980 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:38980 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
8/6/2015 3:02:03 AM.990 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:47779 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
8/6/2015 3:02:04 AM.306 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
8/6/2015 3:02:04 AM.570 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
8/6/2015 3:02:04 AM.734 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
8/6/2015 3:02:06 AM.723 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
8/6/2015 3:02:06 AM.930 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
8/6/2015 3:02:07 AM.867 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/6/2015 3:02:07 AM.867 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/6/2015 3:02:07 AM.868 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/6/2015 3:02:07 AM.966 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

LOG #2 (NO VPN except non-working TOR NW) :

```
8/6/2015 14:26:13 PM.281 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
8/6/2015 14:26:13 PM.281 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
8/6/2015 14:26:14 PM.141 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Connection refused [WSAECONNREFUSED ]; CONNECTREFUSED; count 3; recommendation warn; host C16B543C6DEF3A1310FFBBAB423217B47EEE1A97 at 192.36.41.152:45573) 
8/6/2015 14:26:14 PM.141 [WARN] 2 connections have failed: 
8/6/2015 14:26:14 PM.141 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
8/6/2015 14:26:24 PM.156 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Connection refused [WSAECONNREFUSED ]; CONNECTREFUSED; count 6; recommendation warn; host C16B543C6DEF3A1310FFBBAB423217B47EEE1A97 at 192.36.41.152:45573)
8/6/2015 14:26:24 PM.156 [WARN] 5 connections have failed: 
8/6/2015 14:26:24 PM.156 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
8/6/2015 14:26:24 PM.156 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
8/6/2015 14:26:49 PM.578 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Connection refused [WSAECONNREFUSED ]; CONNECTREFUSED; count 9; recommendation warn; host C16B543C6DEF3A1310FFBBAB423217B47EEE1A97 at 192.36.41.152:45573) 
8/6/2015 14:26:49 PM.578 [WARN] 8 connections have failed: 
8/6/2015 14:26:49 PM.578 [WARN]  6 connections died in state handshaking 
(TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
8/6/2015 14:26:49 PM.578 [WARN]  2 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

Comment: This is an error suggesting that you don't have a stable connection to the Internet or something is blocking access to your first node. Make sure there are no other Firewalls or connectivity issues that could be blocking it. Do you have an AV that is trying to inspect your HTTPS traffic?

Comment: Could be my connection!

Comment: I deactivated some protection modules in my AV, but no matter what I did i had no effect on my connection to the TOR Network. Anyway the problem is solved somehow. Tor Browser works again. I just had to use a diffrent connection. Don't know why TOR cannot connect while using PowerLan